# Wrong output from MobileNet SSD V2 converted tflite model

Tags: c++, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

I am working on object detection application on android using the TensorflowLite C++API. When I convert [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz) model to tflite, output of converted tflite model differs from output of originally provided .pb file on the same test images.

**Converting the .pb file to .tflite**

Terminal Command(I used [this link](https://gist.github.com/apivovarov/eff80275d0f72e4582c105921919b852) for help.):

```
python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py --pipeline_config_path=/content/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix=/content/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt --output_directory=/tmp/tflite_graph --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

The above command threw an error:

> google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 109:7 : Message type
>   "object_detection.protos.SsdFeatureExtractor" has no field named
>   "batch_norm_trainable"

The error was resolved after following the steps suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4066#issuecomment-568371340). I commented out the 'batch_norm_trainable' tag from the 'pipeline.config' file.

But, the detection output of the converted tflite model differs from that of the originaly provided .pb file. How do i convert the .pb files into .tflite so that .tflite file gives the correct output?

**Output Images:**

1. Using .pb (and .pbtxt) files: [pb_output_image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pXJE.jpg) [pb_output_image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1GBH.jpg)
2. Using converted .tflite file: [tflite_output_image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixONR.jpg) [tflite_output_image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXHOw.jpg)

**Versions used:**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Device: QUALCOMM MSM8996 for arm64(Development Board)(Android 9), motorola one power(Android 10)
- TensorFlow version(installed on Ubuntu, used for conversion): 1.15
- TensorFlow version(for tflite used in Android device, built from source): 2.1.0
- Python version: 3.6.9
- Bazel version: 2.0.0
- GCC/Compiler version: 8.3.0

Any help/ guidance at all would be appreciated.

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

try using Keras with tensorflow as the backend